# Using unmanaged C++ code in C# returns 0 for all type double

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling, unmanaged

I am trying to write  a simple calculator DLL in C++ and use the DLL in my C# GUI. However, I am always getting "0" as my return value for any use of the double type.
This is the C++ side:

MathDLL.h

```
#ifndef MATH_DLL_H
#define MATH_DLL_H

#define MATHMANAGERDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" MATHMANAGERDLL_API double __stdcall Add(double x, double y);

#endif //MATH_DLL_H
```

MathDLL.cpp

```
#include "MathDLL.h"
#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(push, off)
#endif
#define NULL 0
MathManager* mathManager;

MATHMANAGERDLL_API double __stdcall Add(double x, double y)
{
    if (mathManager == NULL)
        return false;

    return mathManager->add(x, y);
}
#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(pop)
#endif
```

MathManager.h

```
#ifndef MATH_MANAGER_H
#define MATH_MANAGER_H
class MathManager
{
public:
    MathManager();
    ~MathManager();

    double __stdcall add(double x, double y);
};

#endif //MATH_MANAGER_H
```

MathManager.cpp

```
#include "MathManager.h"

MathManager::MathManager()
{

}

MathManager::~MathManager()
{

}

double __stdcall MathManager::add(double x, double y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

I am importing the DLL functions like so in C#:

SomeWinFormApp.cs

```
...
// Import Math Calculation Functions (MathDLL.h)
    [DllImport("MATH_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "Add")]
    public static extern double Add(double x, double y);
```

When I call Add(), I am getting a return value of 0. I even edited the C++ side to just

```
double __stdcall MathManager::add(double x, double y)
{
    return 1.0;
}
```

But I still get 0. What could be wrong here? I was getting PInvoke errors earlier, which is why I changed to __stdcall. If I used __cdecl, I would still get 0's.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the 0 is not the result of this being activated? `if (mathManager == NULL)
        return false;`. Try returning `50.0` instead of `false`.

Comment: How do you call it in C#?

Comment: @Matt: I mean `add(double x, double y)` is never called. The C++ entrypoint from C# is `Add` not `add`

Comment: It is a *lot* more obvious if you use `return NAN` instead of `return false`, false just isn't a very good *double* value.  Having that MathManager object created requires immaculate conception.  Focus on learning how to debug this code, Project > Properties > Debug tab to enable unmanaged debugging.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Indeed! That was the issue. So the pointers cause the issue! Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad. It was kind of obvious but I couldn't test it, and the fact that it's zero is luck (although it's likely to be zero if it's a global but I wouldn't bet on it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you declare that

```
MathManager* mathManager;
```

which is not defined. You're lucky it's actually NULL, thus your protection code works and returns `false`.

```
if (mathManager == NULL) return false;
```

you could do much simply without any pointers:

```
MathManager mathManager;

MATHMANAGERDLL_API double __stdcall Add(double x, double y)
{        
    return mathManager.add(x, y);
}
```